# Cmake is Unable to Configure Project for Visual Studios 10 amd64

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, point-cloud-library

I am trying to get CMAKE to create a project for msvc 10 express edition for x64 architecture.  I have both MSVC 2010 Express and Windows SDK 7.1 installed.

If I start CMake Normally I can create a 32 bit project, however it fails to make a 64 bit project.  I have also Tried starting CMAKE from within the Windows SDK Command Prompt (cl cmd maps to x64 version) however It still fails with the following.

```
Found Windows SDK v7.1: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 Win64
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 Win64 -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/pclt/PCL/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
  cmTryCompileExec1400574213.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug

  Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1

  [Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.296]

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007.  All rights reserved.



  Build started 1/14/2013 8:15:59 AM.

  Project
  "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\pclt\PCL\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec1400574213.vcxproj"
  on node 1 (default targets).

  PrepareForBuild:

    Creating directory "cmTryCompileExec1400574213.dir\Debug\".
    Creating directory "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\pclt\PCL\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  InitializeBuildStatus:

    Creating "cmTryCompileExec1400574213.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec1400574213.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

  ClCompile:

    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTryCompileExec1400574213.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/pclt/PCL/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec1400574213.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\pclt\PCL\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c  /Zm1000 /GZ 

  C:\Program Files
  (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(146,5):
  error : Required file "" is missing.
  [C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\pclt\PCL\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec1400574213.vcxproj]


  Done Building Project
  "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\pclt\PCL\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec1400574213.vcxproj"
  (default targets) -- FAILED.



  Build FAILED.




  "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\pclt\PCL\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec1400574213.vcxproj"
  (default target) (1) ->

  (ClCompile target) -> 

    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(146,5): error : Required file "" is missing. [C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\pclt\PCL\bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec1400574213.vcxproj]



      0 Warning(s)
      1 Error(s)



  Time Elapsed 00:00:00.12





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues on Win7, and was getting the same error - The C compiler "cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

The solution that worked for me :

1. On Windows Donot run cmake on the cygwin terminal.
2. Run it from the command prompt, AND also ensure that you have admin rights, 
   In windows 7 you can start command prompt as administrator by going to 
   Start->All programs->Accessories-> (Right Click on Command Prompt) and Select "Run as administrator"

Then run `cmake <your source>` 
Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: After trying multiple things, finally step 2 was the catch for me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 6):

I found that my x64 compilers were destroyed by installing SP 1. Try this update to restore them :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422