# CMake configuring fails. "cl.exe is not able to compile a simple test program"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am trying to build a solution for MSVC++2010 using CMake. Since I installed Visual Studio 2012 that does not work anymore. CMake comes with the following error message:
"The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program."

While searching a solution for my problem I found this topic ([Cmake is Unable to Configure Project for Visual Studios 10 amd64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319247/cmake-is-unable-to-configure-project-for-visual-studios-10-amd64/14471934#14471934)) which though adresses my problem but the solution doesn't work for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have had similar problems and ended up giving admin rights to devenv.exe. Note: by adding it to the properties of devenv.exe in Program Files

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem on Win7.
What worked for me is what @Andre suggested in the comment:

1. Right-Click->Properties on `cl.exe` in your VS install directory (the exact path appears in the CMake error);
2. Choose the Compatibility Tab;
3. Check "Run this program as administrator" in the "Privilege Level" box.

Comment: This isn't working for me, please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392976/cmake-cl-exe-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program. Also cl.exe (which is an XML file) doesn't have a compatibility tab, these should can only be done for cl, in the same folder.

Comment: @omgzor You have the "Hide extensions for known file types" option enabled.  `cl` is actually `cl.exe`, and `cl.exe` is actually `cl.exe.config`.  I recommend disabling this setting.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. The above solution didn't work out for me. My problem was solved after looking into [this post](http://delta3d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?showtopic=22426).

First, check if you have .NET 4.5 on your system. If you do, that is very likely causing the problem. Try either upgrading to VS2010 SP1 or downgrade .NET to 4.0

**CAUSES:**

This error appears because you have installed Visual C++ 2012 after you have actually installed Visual C++ 2010 in your system; another cause is because .net Framework 4.5 replace .net Framework 4.0; .net Framework corrupted files;

**HOW TO SOLVE**

Uninstall .NET Framework 4.5 from your system; then download .NET Framework 4.0 and install it; this should fix your problem;

Answer (score 7):

I have met this problem, and I fixed by this way. You should run cmake in a console, 
command like

```
>vcvars32  (to set some system vars, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvar32.bat)

>cmake .. -G"NMake Makefiles" (.. is your code folder) 

>nmake  (It will work well!)
```

You should do this jod in one console, don't open another.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the excatly same problem. I solved by add a command before cmake

`call "C:/Program Files (x86)/VC/vcvarsall.bat" amd64`

The path of vcvarsall.bat and the architecture maybe different on your computer.

According to [Usage of vcvarsall.bat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx), this command is to set up proper environment variable for command-line compilation.

Comment: similar to Zheng Size

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017 and using cmake, I was getting the below error message

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.14.26433.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.14.26433.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

And I resolved the issue by setting the build environment by running vcvars140.bat script (as shown below).

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext\vcvars> .\vcvars140.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Microsoft Visual C++ compiler & linker *on a shell*, you’ve got to set [some specific environmental variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65812244/4510033), `PATH`, `INCLUDE`, and `LIB`.