# CMake: "cl.exe not able to compile a simple test program"

Tags: cmake, dcmtk

I want to build DCMTK in Visual Studio 2010.

I followed the advice here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590947/cmake-configuring-fails-cl-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program), as the image shows.

[image]
And I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you run cmake?

Comment: using the windows gui

Comment: I suspect it means using cmake-gui. What project generator have you selected?

Comment: Try running cmake-gui from a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt.

Comment: @Sergey: I used Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @drescherjm: I did that, when running configure I get the following error: CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/dcmtk_23432/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake

Comment: Check if that file exits. I mean I have CMakeCCompiler.cmake in X:\x64.6\VC.100\Libraries\DCMTK-3.6.0\CMakeFiles\2.8.12.2 for my DCMTK version 3.6.0 with the binary folder I set at X:\x64.6\VC.100\Libraries\DCMTK-3.6.0

Comment: Also I never ever have to mess with any windows compatibility settings to build DCMTK on windows 7, 8, 2012 using cmake and Visual Studio 2010 Pro or Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @drescherjm: no,the file doesn't exist. I have "CMakeRCCompiler.cmake" there. 

These errors appear on one of my machines, where I recently uninstalled VS2013, not in the other. I tried a re-installation/repair of VS2010 after getting this crap. Didn't work.

Comment: You may have to clear the build folder and start again.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following script before running cmake.

```
>vcvars32  (to set some system vars, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat)
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590947/cmake-configuring-fails-cl-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program/24024015#24024015)

**The solution is:**

First, check if you have .NET 4.5 on your system. If you do, that is very likely causing the problem. Try either upgrading to VS2010 SP1 or downgrade .NET to 4.0

**CAUSES:**

This error appear because you have installed Visual C++ 2012 after you have actually installed Visual C++ 2010 in your system; another cause is because .net Framework 4.5 replace .net Framework 4.0; .net Framework corrupted files;

**HOW TO SOLVE:**

Uninstall .NET Framework 4.5 from your system; then download .NET Framework 4.0 and install it; this should fix your problem;