# Building a simple project with vcpkg on Windows results in "This app can't run on your PC" and "Access denied" errors

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, vcpkg

I am following this example for building a simple CMake project with vcpkg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/examples/manifest-mode-cmake

Unfortunately, in the CMake configuration step I get some strange errors:

CMake logs:

```
1> CMake generation started for configuration: 'x64-debug'.
1> Environment settings:
1>     CommandPromptType=Native
1>     DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
1>     ExtensionSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs
1>     EXTERNAL_INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\cppwinrt
1>     Framework40Version=v4.0
1>     FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
1>     FrameworkDir64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
1>     FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
1>     FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
1>     INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\cppwinrt
1>     LIB=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.20348.0\\um\x64
1>     LIBPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.20348.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.20348.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
1>     Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.20348.0\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x64;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x32;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\VSCodium\bin;C;C:\Program Files\Cppcheck;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\tools\winfetch;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\david.harabagiu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\david.harabagiu\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\david.harabagiu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\NASM;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg
1>     PROMPT=$P$G
1>     UCRTVersion=10.0.20348.0
1>     UniversalCRTSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
1>     VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\
1>     VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\
1>     VCPKG_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg
1>     VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\
1>     VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.36.32532\
1>     VCToolsVersion=14.37.32822
1>     VS170COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\
1>     VSCMD_ARG_app_plat=Desktop
1>     VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH=x64
1>     VSCMD_ARG_no_logo=1
1>     VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH=x64
1>     VSCMD_DEBUG=5 
1>     VSCMD_VER=17.7.4
1>     VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\
1>     WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.20348.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.20348.0
1>     WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\
1>     WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
1>     WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.20348.0\
1>     WindowsSdkVerBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.20348.0\
1>     WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.20348.0\
1>     __DOTNET_ADD_64BIT=1
1>     __DOTNET_PREFERRED_BITNESS=64
1>     __VSCMD_PREINIT_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x64;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x32;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\VSCodium\bin;C;C:\Program Files\Cppcheck;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\tools\winfetch;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\david.harabagiu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\david.harabagiu\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\david.harabagiu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\NASM;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
1>     SystemDrive=C:
1>     ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
1>     USERDNSDOMAIN=DEV.THEGREENBOW
1>     ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
1>     ChocolateyInstall=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
1>     PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
1>     TMP=C:\Users\DAVID~1.HAR\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
1>     ThreadedWaitDialogDpiContext=-4
1>     PkgDefApplicationConfigFile=C:\Users\david.harabagiu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_9fe5e3e7\devenv.exe.config
1>     PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e0d
1>     ServiceHubLogSessionKey=42E50DF4
1>     FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
1>     FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
1>     LOGONSERVER=\\GILLESPIE
1>     TEMP=C:\Users\DAVID~1.HAR\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     USERNAME=david.harabagiu
1>     SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
1>     VSSKUEDITION=Community
1>     OneDrive=C:\Users\david.harabagiu\OneDrive
1>     USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DEV
1>     CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     VisualStudioDir=C:\Users\david.harabagiu\Documents\Visual Studio 2022
1>     ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
1>     VS_Perf_Session_GCHeapCount=2
1>     VSAPPIDDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
1>     HOMEPATH=\Users\david.harabagiu
1>     COMPUTERNAME=DEVRPCT051
1>     ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
1>     CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     VisualStudioVersion=17.0
1>     VisualStudioEdition=Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
1>     GCExpConfigUsedInSession=3
1>     SignInWithHomeTenantOnly=False
1>     DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
1>     HOMEDRIVE=C:
1>     windir=C:\WINDOWS
1>     NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
1>     OS=Windows_NT
1>     ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=1
1>     ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
1>     ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
1>     PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
1>     VSLANG=1033
1>     PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
1>     ChocolateyToolsLocation=C:\tools
1>     APPDATA=C:\Users\david.harabagiu\AppData\Roaming
1>     USERDOMAIN=DEV
1>     PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
1>     USERPROFILE=C:\Users\david.harabagiu
1>     LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\david.harabagiu\AppData\Local
1>     ChocolateyLastPathUpdate=133219661126918923
1>     CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
1>     PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
1>     VSAPPIDNAME=devenv.exe
1>     MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly=true
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:/vcpkg_test/out/install/x64-debug"   "D:\vcpkg_test" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: D:/vcpkg_test/out/build/x64-debug
1> [CMake] -- Running vcpkg install
1> [CMake] Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
1> [CMake] All requested packages are currently installed.
1> [CMake] Total install time: 300 ns
1> [CMake] cxxopts provides CMake targets:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
1> [CMake]     find_package(cxxopts CONFIG REQUIRED)
1> [CMake]     target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE cxxopts::cxxopts)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] The package fmt provides CMake targets:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
1> [CMake]     target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     # Or use the header-only version
1> [CMake]     find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
1> [CMake]     target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE fmt::fmt-header-only)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] range-v3 provides CMake targets:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
1> [CMake]     find_package(range-v3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
1> [CMake]     target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE range-v3::meta range-v3::concepts range-v3::range-v3)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] -- Running vcpkg install - done
1> [CMake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.20348.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32824.0
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
1> [CMake]   The C++ compiler
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   It fails with the following output:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     Change Dir: D:/vcpkg_test/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-tmdcsa
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe cmTC_b4357.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:n && MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework
1> [CMake]     Build started 9/25/2023 10:59:03 AM.
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     Project "D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
1> [CMake]     PrepareForBuild:
1> [CMake]       Creating directory "cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\".
1> [CMake]       Creating directory "D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\Debug\".
1> [CMake]       Creating directory "cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\cmTC_b4357.tlog\".
1> [CMake]     InitializeBuildStatus:
1> [CMake]       Creating "cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\cmTC_b4357.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1> [CMake]       Touching "cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\cmTC_b4357.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1> [CMake]     ClCompile:
1> [CMake]       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W1 /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\testCXXCompiler.cxx"
1> [CMake]       Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.37.32824 for x64
1> [CMake]       testCXXCompiler.cxx
1> [CMake]       Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1> [CMake]       cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W1 /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\testCXXCompiler.cxx"
1> [CMake]     Link:
1> [CMake]       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\Debug\cmTC_b4357.exe" /INCREMENTAL /ILK:"cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\cmTC_b4357.ilk" /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/vcpkg_test/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-tmdcsa/Debug/cmTC_b4357.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/vcpkg_test/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-tmdcsa/Debug/cmTC_b4357.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 cmTC_b4357.dir\Debug\testCXXCompiler.obj
1> [CMake]       cmTC_b4357.vcxproj -> D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\Debug\cmTC_b4357.exe
1> [CMake]     PostBuildEvent:
1> [CMake]       setlocal
1> [CMake]       C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1" -targetBinary D:/vcpkg_test/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-tmdcsa/Debug/cmTC_b4357.exe -installedDir "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin" -OutVariable out
1> [CMake]       if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
1> [CMake]       :cmEnd
1> [CMake]       endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
1> [CMake]       :cmErrorLevel
1> [CMake]       exit /b %1
1> [CMake]       :cmDone
1> [CMake]       if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
1> [CMake]       :VCEnd
1> [CMake]       Access is denied.
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: The command "setlocal [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1" -targetBinary D:/vcpkg_test/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-tmdcsa/Debug/cmTC_b4357.exe -installedDir "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin" -OutVariable out [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :cmEnd [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :cmErrorLevel [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: exit /b %1 [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :cmDone [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :VCEnd" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command. [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     Done Building Project "D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     Build FAILED.
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     "D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
1> [CMake]     (PostBuildEvent target) -> 
1> [CMake]       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: The command "setlocal [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1" -targetBinary D:/vcpkg_test/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-tmdcsa/Debug/cmTC_b4357.exe -installedDir "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin" -OutVariable out [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :cmEnd [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :cmErrorLevel [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: exit /b %1 [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :cmDone [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3075: :VCEnd" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command. [D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj]
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]         0 Warning(s)
1> [CMake]         1 Error(s)
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     Time Elapsed 00:00:03.71
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:/vcpkg_test/out/install/x64-debug"   "D:\vcpkg_test" 2>&1"' execution failed with error: ''C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:/vcpkg_test/out/install/x64-debug"   "D:\vcpkg_test" 2>&1"' returned with exit code: 1'.
```

And this thing pops up twice:

[image]

My setup:

- Visual Studio 2022 Community
- Windows 10 x64 (build 19045.3448)
- MSVC v143 - VS 2022
- Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.20348.0

My CMakePresets.json:

```json
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
      {
        "name": "windows-base",
        "hidden": true,
        "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
        "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
        "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
        "architecture": "x64",
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl.exe",
          "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl.exe",
          "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\vcpkg\\scripts\\buildsystems\\vcpkg.cmake"
        },
        "condition": {
          "type": "equals",
          "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
          "rhs": "Windows"
        }
      },
        {
            "name": "x64-debug",
            "displayName": "x64 Debug",
            "inherits": "windows-base",
            "architecture": {
                "value": "x64",
                "strategy": "external"
            },
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "x64-release",
            "displayName": "x64 Release",
            "inherits": "x64-debug",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for vcpkg_test, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project(fibonacci CXX)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED)
find_package(range-v3 REQUIRED)
find_package(cxxopts REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(fibo main.cxx)

target_link_libraries(fibo
  PRIVATE
    fmt::fmt
    range-v3::range-v3
    cxxopts::cxxopts)
```

vcpkg.json:

```json
{
  "dependencies": [
    "cxxopts",
    "fmt",
    "range-v3"
  ]
}
```

vcpkg-configuration.json:

```json
{
  "default-registry": {
    "kind": "git",
    "baseline": "638b1588be3a265a9c7ad5b212cef72a1cad336a",
    "repository": "https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg"
  },
  "registries": [
    {
      "kind": "artifact",
      "location": "https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-ce-catalog/archive/refs/heads/main.zip",
      "name": "microsoft"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

- deleting the CMake cache
- using the NMake generator
- using the Visual Studio 17 2022 generator
- running CMake from the command line
- Running Visual Studio as administrator
- Changing the properties vc.exe and cmake.exe executables to run only as administrator in the "Compatibility" tab
- Unchecking "Read-only" from the folder properties of the build directory.
- Re-installing Visual Studio

Comment: Please show cmake logs.

Comment: I think there are two tabs - error tab and output tab. I think all compilation output logs are in output tab.  You have shared the error tab details. Output tab should have entire cmake logs.

Comment: I added them to my post now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590947/cmake-configuring-fails-cl-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program - check this out, may help.

Comment: It doesn't help. I already saw that.

Comment: Did you try deleting the build directory completely and trying to Generate CMake files again? (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-hello-w/401228#T-N635538)

Comment: Yes, I do that every time before trying something new

Comment: from the log,seems the important lines are after `Access is denied`. Error is MSB3075 (web search -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb3075). I would try manually doing some of the stuff if you can (from a visual studio command prompt -- assume this is how you're already running). What happens if you type `cl` on the command line for example? Hopefully the file `D:\vcpkg_test\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-tmdcsa\cmTC_b4357.vcxproj` is available and will give you some clues. Maybe try running it with MSBuild?

Comment: TBH, MSBuild is not a great build system. You could spend a lot of time on this and get MSBuild working. But why not use ninja, which is a great build system (see, e.g., https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-linux-development-with-visual-studio-incremental-build-improvements-and-expanded-shell-support)? Just change the generator to `Ninja` from `Visual Studio 17 2022` . And if ninja fails also, you might get some more information.

Comment: Ninja didn't work either. I found a last resort solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I decided in the end to re-do the development setup again on a virtual machine and it works. Apparently something is broken in my Windows installation. I will ask the IT guy to do a clean re-install of the OS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).