# The C compiler cl.exe is not able to compile a simple test program on clion

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion

**I am trying to add the Visualstudio tool chain on clion, but it seems that Cmake has encountered some problems. The detailed error report is as follows**

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at S:/Clion/CLion 2023.3.4/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

I have tried a few ways that I could find to fix the problem such as,

- adding `set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY),
- add_compile_options(-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED=ON)`before the` project(Motion_control)`.

They did not work. Hope someone can answer my question, thank you very much.

Comment: CMake creates a log-file where you can see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake configuring fails. "cl.exe is not able to compile a simple test program"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590947/cmake-configuring-fails-cl-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program)

Comment: I just solved the problem by running Clion with the Administrator rights

Comment: ***by running Clion with the Administrator rights*** That will can cause you future problems.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you for your reminder. I have just started to learn to develop qt on clion. I need to configure Visual C++ because I want to develop Pylon, so I encountered such a problem. I have tried many methods on the Internet, but currently, only execution as an administrator works. So can you tell me what type of trouble this will cause?